# Remote Stream not working in Kurento client

Tags: kurento, fiware-kurento

I have setup Kurento Media Server 6+ in AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance. Both STUN and TURN server are also configured. But when I try to access from my local client, it does not work and remote stream hello world tutorial keeps on loading. If i setup the server locally, I am able to see video in remote stream, but not working from aws remote server. All UDP and TCP ports are also enabled in Security Configuration. Can someone help in resolving this issue?